# Get Gridview RowIndex outside of the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Button1 is inside a Panel, I want to access the rowindex so that I will hide that Imagebutton. But when I enter debug mode, the GridView1.SelectedIndex has a null value. pleaase help!

```
  protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex == Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedIndex))
                {
                    ImageButton StopButton = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("stopImageButton");
                    ImageButton StartButton = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("startImageButton");
                    StopButton.Visible = true;
                    StartButton.Visible = false;          
                }
            }
        }

        this.StopTimeNotesPanel_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: What u mean by ' I will hide that Imagebutton' also the selectedindex occurs when you select a row in the gridview that's why you cannot get the value If you click on an external button

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but is a row actually selected? Clicking the button may not select the row.

Comment: I have a gridview that contains a column for Imagebutton per row.

Comment: Run it again, but please post the result of `e.RowIndex` from the debugger.

Comment: it says. "object not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: the argument which is passed to the function, `e`, is that null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that Button is inside a panel. To be able to handle GridView events effectively, use a button inside Gridview itself.

OR if you still want to use button in panel,  then,

1.) First Add a select button inside Gridview. Select a row using the select button and

2.) click the button in Panel.

GridView.SelectedIndex is set only when you have selected a row of Grid view. Two ways are possible:

1.) Set AutoGenerateSelectButton property to true.

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
       datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
       autogenerateselectbutton="True"
       runat="server">
```

2.) Add yourself a buttonField inside  section of gridView as:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        runat="server">
       <columns>
          <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
            commandname="Select"
            headertext="Select Customer" 
            text="Select"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" 
            headertext="Company Name"/>
       </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Now after a row is selected, two events of GridView will be fired:
selectedindexchanging & selectedindexchanged.

Only when required, do this step below to get SelectedRow in SelctedIndexChangedEvent

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
    MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text; // just for Display

  }
```

Now, inside your button click event , get the selected index:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int i = CustomersGridView.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for for your `foreach` loop:

```
ImageButton StopButton = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("stopImageButton");
ImageButton StartButton = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("startImageButton");
StopButton.Visible = true;
StartButton.Visible = false;
```

Comment: It would apply to ALL of the ROWS. I only want the SELECTED ROW not all of them